# cat multiple .csv files while keeping the original filename as a column

Tags: merge, cat

Hoping for a command that merges multiple csv files in a folder but dumps the original filename in a column in the concatenated file.

Comment: What is your operating system? Linux/Unix (you tagged cat)?

Comment: macOS high sierra